# Detecting, when an Oracle server stops being "PRIMARY"

Tags: oracle, failover

Our application needs to (attempt to) shut down and begin failing over to the backup location, when the Oracle database begins to do the same.

The query to check the Oracle-server's status is:

```sql
select DATABASE_ROLE from v$database
```

When that returns anything other than `PRIMARY`, we want to start packing.

Though the check is easy enough, I'd like to implement it *without polling* -- that is, without repeatedly performing the above query. Oracle's own example shows, [how to run a stored procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_dcn.htm) upon a table change, but I don't think, that'll help me. It is also not obvious, the mechanism will work for the the special table (view?) like `v$database`.

How can an Oracle-client program learn, that the server it is connected to is no longer primary -- without polling it?

I'm also curious, how to learn, when your server becomes primary -- but I presume, the mechanism will be the same...

@SayanMalakshinov below explains, that there is a "system event" generated automatically, when the role changes -- great. But how would a client-side program (rather than a server-side stored procedure) learn about it happening?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly do you want to do automatically, but you can read about Role Transition Triggers, ie System level trigger `AFTER DB_ROLE_CHANGE`

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/role_management.htm#SBYDB4772

> 9.1.5 Role Transition Triggers
> The DB_ROLE_CHANGE system event is signaled whenever a role transition occurs. This system event is signaled immediately if the database is open when the role transition occurs, or the next time the database is opened if it is closed when a role transition occurs.
>
> The DB_ROLE_CHANGE system event can be used to fire a trigger that performs a set of actions whenever a role transition occurs.

Comment: Awesome!.. Would you know the C API for learning of such an event being triggered?

Comment: @MikhailT. I haven't understood your question. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want a client-side program to learn of this event _as soon as it happens_ -- without repeatedly polling. Is it possible for an Oracle client to tell the server: "Please, notify me, when `DB_ROLE_CHANGE` happens?"

Comment: There are a lot of different options: you can send email from your trigger, or execute external script (also a few different ways: using dbms_scheduler, or external procedure, or internal java procedure, etc...), or send HTTP request using UTL_HTTP, or event send a TCP message using UTL_TCP, etc...

Comment: `UTL_TCP`? Wow, I didn't even know about [it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_tcp.htm).  Thanks. Can you describe these in your answer, so I can accept it? Do these options require admin-privileges, though?

Comment: No, it's different question (to be honest few different question). I should ask another question more precisely what exactly do you want to try: tcp, http, email, external procs, etc...